# How to apply free shipping promo code to only one shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I think it is a default Magento functionality, when we create a promo code for free shipping it is applying on all the shipping methods and rates for all the shipping methods showing zero.

[image]

Is that any way I can apply free shipping on only Flat Rate and other shipping options will show their prices.

My rule setting in admin as below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple, you just need to add an additional condition

[image]

Comment: I already tried this but still it is showing zero for all shipping methods.

Comment: Could you please confirm if FREE SHIPPING method is not enabled from System>>Configuration>>Shipping Method ?

Comment: Yes Free shipping method is disabled in admin. Also it was my mistake, I kept "Any" instead of "All". Now I changed it to "If All of these condition are True" but now it is showing rates for all the shipping method, for flat rate as well.

Comment: It is showing rates for all, because after changing it from "Any" to "All" now I am not able to apply coupon code. showing me Coupon code not valid. I have for shipping methods enabled right now.

Comment: You don't need to apply coupon code. disable coupon from Rule Information

Comment: I want this for particular customers.

Comment: You can have the rule for particular customer group... Create a customer group and add that customer into that group. Make the rule apply to only that group